# Bootstrap 4 tooltip stuck using Datatables.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables, bootstrap-4

**Scenario:** Load the datatables grid using server side processing. Set the tooltip on the title column. When the mouse hovers the tooltip is shown.

**Issue:** I got the tooltip working. but found one issue that I couldn't solve.

1. Hover on one of the title, which shows the tooltip

[image]

2. While keeping the mouse hovered on the title, change the show 10 records to 25 records using keyboard.

[image]

3. After the records are loaded, the tooltip is stuck on the screen.

[image]

Here is my code snippet

```
var table = $('#list-of-product').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "info": true,
            "stateSave": false,
            "bFilter": false,
            "drawCallback": function (settings, json) {
                $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('update');
                //$("#list-of-product tbody tr > td").tooltip('hide');
            },
            "ajax": {
                "url": "@Url.Action("GetProducts", "LandingPage")",
                "type": "POST"
            },
            "language": {
                "paginate": {
                    "previous": "<<",
                    "next": ">>"
                },
                "info": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_",
                "lengthMenu": "Show _MENU_",
                "search": "",
                "searchPlaceholder": "Search..."
            },
            "columns": [
                            { "data": "LineOfBusiness", "orderable": true },
                            { "data": "Discipline", "orderable": true },
                            { "data": "InventoryProgram", "orderable": true },
                            { "data": "ISBN13", "orderable": true },
                            { "data": "Title", "orderable": true },
                            { "data": "ProductID", "orderable": true },
                            {
                                data: null,
                                className: "text-center",
                                defaultContent: '<a href="#list-of-product" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ContactAssigner"><i class="material-icons">assignment_ind</i></a>',
                                "orderable": false
                            }
            ],
            "order": [[0, "asc"]],
            createdRow: function (row, data, dataIndex) {
                $(row).find('td:eq(4)').attr('title', data["Title"]);
                $(row).find('td:eq(4)').attr('data-toggle', "tooltip");
                //$(row).find('td:eq(4)').tooltip();
            }
        });
```

Any advise would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to hook into this page size change event, and then hide any open tooltips.

```
$('#list-of-product').on('length.dt', function (e, settings, len) {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('hide');
});
```

[Demo on Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/go/rK9IKq60SI)

The `drawCallback` event won't work very well because it's called on init and any time the table is updated, when it may not be necessary to hide all the tooltips.

Comment: Thanks @ZimSystem. It works perfectly. I used this one which also works `drawCallback": function (settings, json) {
                    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
                    $("[id^='tooltip']").tooltip('hide');
                }`

Comment: Thank @RanjithVaradan, yours is working for me. Also working for bootstrap popovers.

Answer (score 0):

**For Bootstarp Popovers use**

````
            dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-4'l><'col-sm-4 text-center'B><'col-sm-4'f>>tp",
            "lengthMenu": [[50, -1], [50, "All"]],
            order: [[1, 'desc']],
            fnDrawCallback: function () {
                $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
                $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');
            },
            "language": {
                "emptyTable": "No Records Founds"
            },
            "ordering": false,
            buttons: [
                { extend: 'csv', title: 'Support Portal', className: 'btn-sm' },
                { extend: 'pdf', title: 'Support Portal', className: 'btn-sm' },
                { extend: 'print', className: 'btn-sm' }
            ]
        });```
````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).